# Finding third to last element in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am currently learning Haskell, but I am having some trouble figuring out how to tackle this problem. I would like my code to find the third to last element of a list, but currently, my code finds the second to last element of a list.

```
antepenultimate :: [a] -> a
antepenultimate [] = error "The list is empty. Cannot return the antepenultimate element."
antepenultimate [x] = error "The list is too short to return the antepenultimate element."
antepenultimate xs = last $ init xs
```

I am not sure how to modify my code so that it returns the elements I want it to. Can anyone offer any pointers?

Comment: What's the obstacle which you have? You've written the code for 2nd from the last element, and there is nothing essentially different about 3rd from the last element. I can't help but suspect that the current code is not created by you.

Comment: @dyukha Funnily enough, I found the solution to my problem when trying to explain myself to you. In that final line of code, I just tacked on another "init". I was definitely just overthinking what had to be done.

Comment: Good, but you should check how it behaves on list `[1, 2]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Damián Rafael Lattenero's answer: it demonstrates how a beginner can use pattern matching to solve this problem. It has the problem, though, that if you want some number other than 3rd-last, you have to rewrite your function; and furthermore the number of cases you write corresponds to how far from the back of the list you want to go. Imagine using this technique for the 100th-last element! It also does a lot of unnecessary work: once you make it past the first set of guards, you know they will never match again; but you're still constantly having to check "Hey, is the rest of the list empty? Does it have one element? What about two?" So as I say, a good solution for a beginner, but not ideal.

duyue's answer addresses these problems, but at the cost of traversing the list twice: once to find its length, and then again to look up the right index. Very simple and clear, but problematic if the list is too large to hold in memory all at once.

It would be better if we could somehow traverse the list just once, keeping in mind at all times the element we saw three steps ago; then when the list ends we can just return the right element. An intermediate solution might be to write this recursion by hand:

```
antepenultimate [] = undefined
antepenultimate [_] = undefined
antepenultimate [_,_] = undefined
antepenultimate (a:b:c:xs) = go a b c xs
  where go a _ _ [] = a
        go a b c (x:xs) = go b c x xs
```

A somewhat more advanced solution uses the well-known technique of zipping a list with an offset version of itself to have access to two items at once:

```
antepenultimate xs = last $ zipWith const xs (drop 2 xs)
```

Finally, someone even more familiar with Haskell might recognize the `zipWith const xs (drop 2 xs)` pattern as being amenable to Applicative style, yielding:

```
antepenultimate = last . (zipWith const <*> drop 2)
```

Some people will argue this is less readable than the previous version; I have no strong opinions on that, but I do think it is the most elegant/advanced even if another approach is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You were somewhere close, but if you want to do it with pattern matching, make the patter with three elements, and in the recursion part, remove from the back:

```
msg = "The list is empty. Cannot return the antepenultimate element."
err = error msg
antepenultimate :: [a] -> a
antepenultimate [] = err
antepenultimate [_] = err
antepenultimate [_,_] = err
antepenultimate [antepenultimateElem,_, _] = antepenultimateElem
antepenultimate xs = antepenultimate $ tail xs
```

examples:

```
   antepenultimate [1,2,3]
=> 1
   antepenultimate [1,2,3,4]
=> 2
   antepenultimate [1,2,3,4,5]
=> 3
   antepenultimate [1,2,3,4,5,6]
=> 4
   antepenultimate [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
=> 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```hs
antepenultimate :: [a] -> a
antepenultimate xs = let xslen = length xs in 
                        if xslen < 3
                            then error "The list is too short to return the antepenultimate element."
                        else xs !! (xslen - 3)
```